# How make a virtual field for view?

Tags: 8, entities

i want a vitual field for print value of sum in another entity :

My 2 custom entity content :

> commandes_entity
>
> commandesLignes_entity reference to commandes_entity

In the commandes_entity i have a view table who liste all my lines.
i want to add a custom column who sum all the children in commandesLignes_entity.

For that i make a field in .module :

```
function hook_views_data()
{

  $data['commandes_entity'] = array(

      'totalCommandeTTC' => array(
          'title' => t('Total Commande TTC'),
          'help' => t("Le total des commandes"),
          'field' => array(
              'id' => 'machine_name',
              'options callback' => 'Drupal\boutique\Controller\TestController::content',

          ),

          'sort' => array(
              'id' => 'standard',
          ),

      ),

  );

return $data;
}
```

This field is in my select field view, when i add it all is ok except one thing :

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'commandes_entity.totalCommandeTTC' in 'field list': SELECT
>   commandes_entity.totalCommandeTTC AS
>   commandes_entity_totalcommandettc, commandes_entity.id AS id FROM
>   {commandes_entity} commandes_entity WHERE (( (commandes_entity.statut
>   LIKE :db_condition_placeholder_0 ESCAPE '\') )) ORDER BY
>   commandes_entity.created DESC LIMIT 21 OFFSET 0; Array (
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => payer )

This field

> totalCommandeTTC

doesn't exist in my table, i want it virtual.

For now my callback just return 'test'.

Any idea for make this field really virtual ?

I try to move it to views group like this :

```
function boutique_views_data()
{

  $data['views'] = array(

      'totalCommandeTTC' => array(
          'title' => t('Total Commande TTC'),
          'help' => t("Le total des commandes"),
          'field' => array(
              'id' => 'machine_name',
              'options callback' => 'Drupal\boutique\Controller\TestController::content',

          ),

          'sort' => array(
              'id' => 'standard',
          ),

      ),

  );

return $data;
}
```

The field is in the Global group but SQL still try to get it into the commandes_entity table.

Comment: In D7 you needed to provide a custom handler for the field, and override the query method. It's probably very similar in D8 but I'm not at the computer to check at the moment

Comment: ok thx Clive i ll check how its done in d7 and try to implement that into d8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank to Clive for guide me :

This is how i make a virtual field :

First you need to create the handler for the field :

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\boutique\Plugin\views\field;

use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\FieldPluginBase;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase;
use Drupal\views\ResultRow;
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;

/**
 * Field handler to present the path to the node.
 *
 * @ingroup views_field_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsField("totalCommandeTTC")
 */
class TotalTTC extends FieldPluginBase {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function init(ViewExecutable $view, DisplayPluginBase $display, array &$options = NULL) {
        parent::init($view, $display, $options);

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function query() {
        }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function render(ResultRow $values) {
       return 'test';
    }

}
```

I remove the query for this handler.

Then in my module file, i use the hook_views_data :

```
function boutique_views_data()
{

  $data['commandes_entity'] = array(

      'totalCommandeTTC' => array(
          'title' => t('Total Commande TTC'),
          'help' => t("Le total TTC des commandes"),
          'field' => array(
              'id' => 'totalCommandeTTC',
          ),


      ),

  );

return $data;
}
```

And the result in views after add the field with views ui :

[image]

The field is Total commande TTC.

Comment: Lovely answer, it is helpful.